# NFe - applet leitura chave privada e publica

Tags: php, java, nfe

Preciso desenvolver um sistema para emitir nota fiscal eletrônica. O meu grande problema é que esse sistema precisa atender o certificado A3 (cartão) e até onde andei lendo com php ainda não é possivel capturar a chave privada e publica do cartão. Pensei então em fazer um applet apenas para ler esses dados e colocar em uma sessão, assim eu poderia utilizar com o php.

Como conheço pouco de Java, gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso, ou é loucura minha. E caso seja possível se alguém tem para me indicar um software onde posso olhar no fonte OU leituras para que eu consiga desenvolver isso.

Caso eu consiga me proponho a postar no projeto [NfePHP](https://github.com/nfephp-org/nfephp/) e contribuir com a comunidade!

Comment: acredito que um desses links possa ajudar http://www.javac.com.br/jc/posts/list/122-nfe-assinatura-dos-xmls-de-envio-de-lote-cancelamento-e-inutilizacao-certificado-a3.page  http://www.javac.com.br/jc/posts/list/1220-duvidas-para-pegar-certificado-digital-resolvido.page    http://www.guj.com.br/java/110442-certificado-a3---nfe/2

Comment: Tem um dos códigos ai que parece promissor Caputo, muito obrigado

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @bigown depois de entender melhor o problema percebi que é extremamente difícil utilizar o A3 com o php já que ele roda em servidor... acabei escolhendo por criar minha própria api, mas utilizar o certificado A1

Comment: Olha Neto, ja tive este mesma questao no passado, e acabei utilizando o certificado A1 mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Já implementei sistemas de emissão de NFSe cujos RPS necessitavam da assinatura com certificado digital e o cliente possuía justamente um do tipo A3.

**Solução simples**: criar um programinha em Java que roda no terminal (task) para fazer a assinatura. Ele se comunica com a API da minha aplicação PHP em busca de lotes sem assinatura, quando encontra um, assina e envia o resultado de volta para API.

A API é bem simples e necessita somente de 2 pontos de acesso:

- um para pegar lotes ainda não assinados;
- outro para submeter a assinatura dos lotes processados.

Segue nesse caminho que você se dá bem (ou me avisa se achar uma solução melhor) :)

Outra alternativa, como disseram anteriormente, é usar um certificado do tipo A1. Conheço muita gente que foi nessa direção.

Abraço

Answer (score 0):

O que funcionaria no seu caso seria um webservice, que poderia ser até simples em java que possibilitasse voce informar uma chave e ele retornasse um booleano ou até mesmo uma string ok e erro, algo do tipo... Java tem muitos componentes que criam WS de forma simples como o jaxws e o próprio springWS, e do lado php com alguns jsons a consulta se tornaria transparente.
 Outra possibilidade seria voce configurar seu tomcat para fazer a validação do certificado e rodar sua aplicação php dentro da camada HTTPS. Desta forma delegaria toda a validação de entrada ao servidor tomcat.